# PHP dropdown box store selected value

Tags: javascript, php, sql

Okay I can't figure this out but how do I echo the $row['price'] depending on which gpu the user selects. updated due to the comments asking me to post more code.#making up the word count because I can't submit without doing this.

```
     <div id="content">
 <table border="1" style="width:auto;">
      <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="checkout.php" method="POST">
          <label for="intel" INTEL Build:</label>
        <?php
  //GPU QUERY
   $sqlgpu="SELECT id, gpu, price, gpuWATT FROM  GPU";
 $result = mysql_query($sqlgpu);
?>
<select id ="gpu"  onChange="sum_all()">
<?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">             '    .$row["gpu"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

}
echo "</select>";
?>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php

  //PSU QUERY
 $sqlpsu="SELECT id, psu, price, psuWATT FROM  PSU";
 $result = mysql_query($sqlpsu);
?>
<select id ="psu"  onChange="sum_all()">
<?php
$pricePsu = 0;

while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo '<option value="'.$rows["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$rows["psu"]. " £" .$rows["price"].'</option>';


}
 ?>
 </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <?php


    //COMPUTERCASE QUERY

 $sqlcomputercase="SELECT id, computercase, price FROM  COMPUTERCASE";
 $result = mysql_query($sqlcomputercase);
  echo "<select name='computercase'>";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'"   title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["computercase"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

  }
  echo "</select>";

   ?>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function sum_all ()
{      var mobo = document.getElementById( "mobo" );
   var cpu = document.getElementById( "cpu" );
 var ram = document.getElementById( "ram" );
var harddrive = document.getElementById( "harddrive" );
 var gpu = document.getElementById( "gpu" );
 // alert( mobo.options[ mobo.selectedIndex ].title );
   var sum = parseInt( mobo.options[ mobo.selectedIndex ].title ) +
        parseInt( cpu.options[ cpu.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
        parseInt( ram.options[ ram.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
        parseInt( harddrive.options[ harddrive.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
        parseInt( gpu.options[ gpu.selectedIndex  ].title );
    document.getElementById( "checkout" ).innerHTML = sum;
  }
</script>
<br/>
  Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: well, yeah. you keep resetting $priceGpu on every iteration of the loop. so you end up with the LAST value you fetched from the db.  how/where do you want to echo this price? you'd need something like `if($row['id'] == $user_selected_gpu) { $price = ... }` to only grab the price for the actual gpu the user selected.

Comment: i just want to echo the price under the dropdown box so its like a total cost

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5, instead use mysqli_* functions. Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for more information

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez did nothing.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez the GPU is adding the correct prices to the sum but the other ones are not working.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez how do i find value the title contains in source code.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez title deffo is getting the prices just looked

Comment: Prices have decimals. Replace `parseInt` by `parseFloat` in the function.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Okay thanks for the help

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I managed to get it fully working now I need to figure out how to POST it to the next page so i can display it in PHP

Comment: I'm back! Post it to next page is easy, I will edit my answer with the necessary changes. If you would like to accept or upvote my answer, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: okay but now its displaying it all in one line and i need to sperate the name from the price so trying to make it explode and store it int different varribles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the sum of several dropdowns :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function sum_all ()
{ var fru = document.getElementById( "fruits" );
  var che = document.getElementById( "cheeses" );
  var sum = parseInt( fru.options[ fru.selectedIndex ].title ) +
            parseInt( che.options[ che.selectedIndex ].title );
  document.getElementById( "total" ).innerHTML = sum;
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="fruits" onchange="sum_all()">
      <option value="1" title="1">Banana</option>
      <option value="2" title="2">Apple</option>
      <option value="3" title="5">Melon</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cheeses" onchange="sum_all()">
      <option value="1" title="12">Cheddar</option>
      <option value="2" title="6">Fresh</option>
      <option value="3" title="15">Mozarella</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    Total: <span id="total"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everytime you select one dropdown, this will show the sum of prices. The "title"s are the prices for the products.

Now let's fix your code :

```
 <div id="content">
    <?php
$link = mysql_connect('root', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $selected = mysql_select_db("database",$link) 
 or die("Could not select examples");


    ?>
      <table border="1" style="width:auto;">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <form action="checkout.php" method="POST">
              <label for="intel" INTEL Build:</label>
                <?php
  //MOTHERBOARD QUERY
  $sql="SELECT id, mobo, price FROM MOBO WHERE mobo LIKE 'INTEL%' ";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
//print '<form action="checkout.php" method="post">';
    print "<select name='mobo'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        print '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["mobo"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

    }
    print "</select>";
  ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php


      //CPU QUERY
  $sqlcpu="SELECT id, cpu, price FROM  CPU WHERE cpu LIKE 'INTEL%' ";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlcpu);

  print   "<select name='cpu'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        print '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["cpu"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

    }
    print "</select>";

    ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php
                 //RAM QUERY
  $sqlram="SELECT id, ram, price FROM RAM ";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlram);

    echo "<select name='ram'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["ram"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php
                 //HARDDRIVE QUERY
  $sqlharddrive="SELECT id, harddrive, price FROM  HARDDRIVE";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlharddrive);

    echo "<select name='harddrive'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["harddrive"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>

            <?php
      //GPU QUERY
  $sqlgpu="SELECT id, gpu, price, gpuWATT FROM  GPU";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlgpu);
?>
    <select id ="gpu"  onChange="sum_all()">
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["gpu"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php

      //PSU QUERY
  $sqlpsu="SELECT id, psu, price, psuWATT FROM  PSU";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlpsu);
    ?>
    <select id ="psu"  onChange="sum_all()">
    <?php
    $pricePsu = 0;

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<option value="'.$rows["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$rows["psu"]. " £" .$rows["price"].'</option>';


    }
   ?>
   </select>

          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <?php


        //COMPUTERCASE QUERY

  $sqlcomputercase="SELECT id, computercase, price FROM  COMPUTERCASE";
  $result = mysql_query($sqlcomputercase);
    echo "<select name='computercase'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'" title="'.$row["price"].'">'.$row["computercase"]. " £" .$row["price"].'</option>';

    }
    echo "</select>";

    ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
<script type="text/javascript">
function sum_all ()
{ var mobo = document.getElementById( "mobo" );
  var cpu = document.getElementById( "cpu" );
  var ram = document.getElementById( "ram" );
  var harddrive = document.getElementById( "harddrive" );
  var gpu = document.getElementById( "gpu" );
  var sum = parseInt( mobo.options[ mobo.selectedIndex ].title ) +
            parseInt( cpu.options[ cpu.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
            parseInt( ram.options[ ram.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
            parseInt( harddrive.options[ harddrive.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
            parseInt( gpu.options[ gpu.selectedIndex  ].title );
  document.getElementById( "total" ).innerHTML = sum;
 }
</script>

         <?php


//echo "Total Cost: £".$grandtotal = $priceMobo + $priceCpu + $priceRam +      $priceHARDDRIVE + $priceGpu + $pricePsu + $priceComputercase;
$_SESSION['checkoutTotal'] = $grandtotal;
echo '<br></br>';
?>
<br/>
Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

I added "title" to all the selects and created more variables in javascript function... and just added the `<span>` at the bottom!

Now let's store the data in the form. The javascript function will store the IDs of the selected items in the form fields, then submits the form, by the way, the form is invisible because we don't want the user to edit it :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sum_all ()
{ var mobo = document.getElementById( "mobo" );
  var cpu = document.getElementById( "cpu" );
  var ram = document.getElementById( "ram" );
  var harddrive = document.getElementById( "harddrive" );
  var gpu = document.getElementById( "gpu" );
  var sum = parseInt( mobo.options[ mobo.selectedIndex ].title ) +
            parseInt( cpu.options[ cpu.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
            parseInt( ram.options[ ram.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
            parseInt( harddrive.options[ harddrive.selectedIndex  ].title ) +
            parseInt( gpu.options[ gpu.selectedIndex  ].title );
  document.getElementById( "total" ).innerHTML = sum;
  // STORE THE "ID"S IN THE FORM FIELDS.
    document.getElementById( "frm_mobo" ).value = mobo.options[ mobo.selectedIndex ].value;
    document.getElementById( "frm_cpu" ).value  = cpu.options[ cpu.selectedIndex ].value;
    document.getElementById( "frm_ram" ).value  = ram.options[ ram.selectedIndex ].value;
    document.getElementById( "frm_hd" ).value   = harddrive.options[ harddrive.selectedIndex ].value;
    document.getElementById( "frm_gpu" ).value  = gpu.options[ gpu.selectedIndex ].value;
    document.getElementById( "frm" ).submit(); // SUBMIT FORM.
}
</script>

<form id="frm" method="post" action="anyname.php" style="display:none;">
  <input type="text" id="frm_mobo" name="frm_mobo"/>
  <input type="text" id="frm_cpu"  name="frm_cpu"/>
  <input type="text" id="frm_ram"  name="frm_ram"/>
  <input type="text" id="frm_hd"   name="frm_hd"/>
  <input type="text" id="frm_gpu"  name="frm_gpu"/>
</form>
```

You will have to create the file "anyname.php" (you choose a better name), to get the data from `$_POST[ "frm_mobo" ]`, `$_POST[ "frm_cpu" ]`, etc., and do something with them.

Comment: the code loaded but changed nothing.

Comment: Oh yes i see but i need to add this price to the CPU as well which is exactly the same except it displays CPUs insted so it will show a grand total

Comment: okay i have multiple dropdown boxes that all have $row['price'] i need to store each one in a variable then add them all up and display in total price variable then echo it so the user knows how much everything costs.

Comment: what JavaScript will I need I don't have experience with this.

Comment: it displays NaN but I don't want an alert i need it to display under the dropdown boxes.